# HTTP Get Request Example in Swift

Tags: json, swift, serialization, nsdictionary

I am following the tutorial posted [Here](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/http-get-request-example-in-swift/) on an HTTP Get Request in Swift.

I am trying to send a get request to my own URL, receive the data as a JSON Object, convert it into an NSDictionary object, and then parse the data, just as the tutorial does.

For some reason, when I do the "NSJSONSerialization" call, I am getting the error thrown:

"The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format."

Here is my code I used:

```
import UIKit

import Foundation

func getObject()
{
    let categoryId: Int = 419247

    let URL = "http://www.URL.com/category/display?category_id=\(categoryId)&_format=json"

    let myURL = NSURL(string: URL)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myURL!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil{
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        do {
            if let convertedJsonIntoDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

                //Parse the data
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error received")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }.resume()
```

}

I then go on to call this function in the classes "override func viewDidLoad() message like such:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    score = 0
    scoreLabel.text = String(score)
    getObject()
}
```

When I type these two lines in my catch block:

```
print(error.localizedDescription)
print(String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

I get this result:

```
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Optional("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:fb=\"http://ogp.me/ns/fb#\" xmlns:og=\"http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/\">\n  <head>\n    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1\" />\n    <title>**MYTITLE**</title>\n    <meta name=\"description\" content=\**MYCONTENT**/>\n    <meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"**CONTENT**" />\n    <meta name=\"msvalidate.01\" content=\"41B97029358C73B43E83E46F81B33636\" />\n    <link rel=\"shortcut icon\" type=\"image/x-icon\" href=\"http://common.csnimages.com/common/misc/favicon.ico\" />\n    <link rel=\"canonical\" href=\"http://www.URL.com\"/>\n    <style>\n      html, body, div, span, h1, h2{\n          margin: 0;\n          padding: 0;\n          border: 0;\n          font-size: 100%;\n          font: inherit;\n          vertical-align: baseline; }\n      body{\n        font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;\n        font-size:13px;\n        color:#4D4D4F;\n        cursor:default;\n        }\n      h1{\n        font-size:30px;\n        font-weight:bold;\n        color:#783163;\n        }\n      h2{\n        font-size:16px;\n        font-weight:bold;\n        }\n      .wrapper{\n        margin:35px auto;\n        width:767px;\n        }\n      .redirect{\n        background:url(data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/*ENGLISH TEXT 100,000 CHARACTERS LONG* (REMOVED 95% OF CHARACTERS FOR LENGTH REASONS) 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);\n\n      var i = new Image(1, 1);\n      i.src = prefix  + q;\n      i.onload = function() {};\n    }\n    catch(e){};\n\n   </script>\n\n  </body>\n</html>\n")
```

I cannot seem to figure this out at all. I have tried many different things and had no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In addition, before I do the "if let convertedJsonIntoDict" call, if I write "print(data!)" it just prints me a long array of hex values

Comment: @Rob thanks for the help. I printed the data and it seems to be correct. Do I need to encode my data before passing it into the function?

And when i print(response), the statusCode is 416

Comment: @Rob the JSON text as in the first print statement you had me do? Because thats not actually printing me JSON data, it seems to be printing something like this:

Optional("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:fb=\"http://ogp.me/ns/fb#\" xmlns:og=\"http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/\">\n  <head>\n    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1\" />\n    <title> *ENGLISH* </title>\n    <meta name=\"description\" content=\"*CONTENT*" />\n 

Etc... Followed by a long string of random characters and some more English.

Comment: @Rob Just realized I should've posted this part before. I'm declaring URL as: "http://<link>&_format=json" so I'm fairly confident it should be in json.

Also, when I actually go to the link, I'm seeing a bunch of JSON (of course)

Comment: @Rob I do have the question mark. I will edit my question with the information that comes out of that print statement right now, my apologies.

Comment: @Rob Hopefully that information helps. I added all the information I have

Comment: @Rob Okay, thanks for the help. Which URL might you be referring to? The one with the 100,000 characters of english?

Comment: @Rob It does seem to open up the html webpage with the images.

Also, using Postman allows me up to send a GET request with the link in the JSON formatting and see the correct JSON

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114480/discussion-between-rob-and-logan).

Comment: Some random tutorial on the web doesn't work. What a surprise. :p // You're trying to decode JSON from this page, but where you say `I get this result` we clearly see that this page returns HTML, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

It isn’t in the right format because it should be an Array, etc. In the following code change the JSON Response type if it gives the error if it doesn’t it should show the JSON data. If the [String:Any] doesn’t work try Array.
A way to do this is to do this code:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: ((url ?? URL(string: "https://google.com"))!)) { [self] (data, response, error) in
        
        do {
            let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
            print(jsonResponse)
            guard let newValue = jsonResponse as? [String:Any] else {
                print("invalid format")
                }
            }

        
        catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        
    task.resume()
}
```